# How can I set wallpaper FIXING? avoid LWP

Tags: android, bitmap, android-wallpaper

I'm making some app that:

1. user pick image from gallery.
2. app do(auto-crop_center image and set wallpaper).

I'm successed to set wallpaper, but it scrolled => live wallpaper.

I want to know:

1. how to set fixed wallpaper
2. I just set non-createscaled bitmap to wallpaper. is android do auto crop bitmap?

   ```
   public void setScreenBitmap(Bitmap bitmapInputed)
   {

   WallpaperManager wpm = WallpaperManager.getInstance(myContext);


   wpm.setWallpaperOffsetSteps(1.0F,1.0F);

   try 
   {
       wpm.setBitmap(bitmapInputed);
   }
   catch (IOException e) 
   {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }

   }
   ```